# Legality of "wellness checks"?

Tags: search-and-seizure, new-hampshire

I have a friend whose apartment was broken into at night while he was sleeping by the police with guns drawn to do a "wellness check" because the mother of a friend of his called 911 and reported him as possibly suicidal. Later they charged him because he grabbed a gun when he heard what he thought were intruders in his house.

What is the legality of such entries?

Obviously, if anonymous 911 calls are acted on, then a "wellness check" could provide the police a pretext to break into anybody's house, since the police can simply have an informant under their control call in an "anonymous" report on someone to generate a "wellness check".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can police enter a dwelling to intervene in a suicide attempt in a state where suicide is not a crime?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3401/can-police-enter-a-dwelling-to-intervene-in-a-suicide-attempt-in-a-state-where-s)

Comment: Your last paragraph basically says “police can commit crimes”. We assume that usually they don’t. Your scenario would be a serious crime.